# Terminating a thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

I'm trying to figure out a way how a piece of Javascript code (in Node.js) can be forced to terminate its execution. Something like this pseudocode:

```
var thread = runAsynchronouslyInThread(function() {
  while(1) {};
});

setTimeout(function() {
  thread.terminate();
}, 1000);
```

I've tried [`threads_a_gogo`](https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) and [`webworker-threads`](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) based on it, but with no luck, `destroy` and `terminate` methods do not interrupt what is executing already. Is there a way to achieve this in Javascript?

I know that this task is not really common in node.js programming, but this is absolutely mandatory in my project's needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `process.exit()` or `process.kill()`

take a look [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) and [here](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal) for their API.

I'm assuming another thread you mean a `child_process`. Node is always single thread.

So, you call `process.exit()` you will kill the whole process if it's not call on a child.

Comment: No, I mean threads, not processes. Those threads which are created by `threads_a_gogo` for example.

Comment: wow. this new stuff to me. I should have read more carefully...

A whole new world awaits me :D